# #[Error] invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'

Tags: c++

I need little help. When I compile my code it give me this error:

> [Error] invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

My code is given below, please point out the mistake:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ptrArry{
private:
    int *ptr;
    int MaxSize;
public:
    ptrArry(){
        ptr=NULL;
        MaxSize=2;
        for(int i=0; i<MaxSize; i++){
            *(ptr+i) = new int[MaxSize];
        }
    }
    void setArry(int val){
        for(int i=0; i<MaxSize; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<MaxSize; j++){
                cout<<"i="<<i<<endl;
                cout<<"j="<<j<<endl;
                ptr=val;
            }
        }
    }
    void getArry(){
        for(int i=0; i<MaxSize; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<MaxSize; j++){
                cout<<"i="<<i;
                cout<<"j="<<j;
                cout<<ptr[i][j];
                cout<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
};
int main() {
    ptrArry obj1;
    obj1.setArry(50);
    obj1.getArry();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the Java tag intentional?

Comment: what´s the deal with java here?

Comment: well, error-messages usually come with a line-number... might be quite helpful to take a closer look at that specific line. And you should **really** read a proper tutorial on memory-management and pointers. Even if that code compiled, it would leak memory like a sieve and receive SIGSEGV in no time.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things I could see:

This line inside `setArray()` function is what's causing it: `ptr=val;`
You're assigning an integer value to a pointer variable - which is what the compiler is complaining about. You should instead be doing this: `*ptr=val;` and by doing so, you're storing the integer value to what's being pointed to by the `ptr` variable.

There's a stray ` in your code between the two braces }} where the class definition ends.

Edit: Thanks to whozcraig's comment below: `*(ptr+i) = new int[MaxSize];` makes very little sense as well.

Comment: You're correct, I had just edited my answer to point out that it's just one of the mistakes I could see straight away. There's also a stray ` character in the code. I'm pretty sure the compiler should have listed more than one error. :)